# Proof rotational invariance of integral in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

i want to show that: for $f\in {C}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^2)$
$$ \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f = \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f\star A$$
so that A is the two dimensional rotation matrix:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(x) & -\sin(x)\\
\sin(x) & \cos(x)
\end{bmatrix} $$
via usage of the one dimensional substitution rule.

Maybe the following identity of A helps?:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(x) & -\sin(x)\\
\sin(x) & \cos(x)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1/\cos(x) & -\sin(x)/\cos(x)\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
\sin(x) & \cos(x)
\end{bmatrix}$$
I know that showing the invariance is easy by using the Determinant of A.

Comment: what is $f$ here?

Comment: f is out of C_c(R^2)

Comment: this follows from the change of variables theorem since $A$ is a diffeomorphism and $|\det A|=1$.

Comment: yes, i know that proof. but i want to proof it manually by using the one dimensional substitution rule...